# ¿Dónde se encuentra el maven embebido de Netbeans 8.0.2?

Tags: netbeans, maven

He estado trabajando con maven en el netbeans y me gustaría usar el maven que ya trae pero ahora desde la consola y no descargarlo de nuevo.

Al abrir la configuración en vez de la ruta me dice maven embebido.

¿Alguien sabe dónde lo puedo encontrar si tengo Netbeans `8.0.2`?

Mi sistema operativo es Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si buscas el archivo `mvn.bat`, lo encontrarás en la carpeta:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat
```

Comment: te refieres al de archivos de programa?

Comment: En efecto. Esa ruta o similar aparece dentro de la primera línea de la salida o consola al ejecutar alguna tarea (Build, Clean, etc.) sobre un proyecto de tipo Maven.

Comment: Ok lo agrego al path y te cuento si funciona

Comment: Funcionó como un maven normal! Gracias